# A single analytic function that can approximate all others

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, approximation-theory

The problem in it's entirety is this:

Given some simply connected domain $U$ then show that there is a function $g\in\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$ such that for any given $f$ there exists a sequence $\zeta_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$ so that $g(z-\zeta_{n})$ converges compactly to $f(z)$ in $U$.

I am fairly certain that the problem should be solved in this manner.

1. There are countably many polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ therefore we can have a sequence $q_{n}$ where every such polynomial appears infinitely many times. **I can show this**.
2. If we have some sequence of non-intersecting balls $V_{n}$ (with centers $\zeta_{n}$) of increasing radius, tending to infinity, then there exists some entire function $g$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}||(g-q_{n})|_{Vn}||=0$. **I can not show this**.
3. There exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ such that $p_n(z)$ converges compactly to $f(z)$. **I can show this**.
4. There exists some subsequence of $q_n$, which we will call $m_{n}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\|(p_n-m_n)|_{Vn}\|=0$. **I can show this**.
5. Therefore, within any compact, and therefore bounded set we have $|f(z)-g(z-\zeta_{mn})| \leq |f(z)-p_n(z)| + |p_n(z)-m_n(z)| + |m_n(z)-g(z-\zeta_{mn})|$, all of which can be made arbitrarily small with a large enough $n$. **I can show this**.

I know there are some presentation details I need to fix, however the idea should be clear for now. The main problem lies in being unable to show step #2. If there are any ideas on how to do this please let me know.

The solution to the problem is so tantalizingly close that I feel that this must be the correct approach. Maybe the idea is to choose some clever $V_n$ or use some powerful approximation result that I don't know about.

Perhaps this is somehow related to Montel's theorem?

Comment: $\text{“}$Given some simply connected domain $U$ then show that there is a function $g\in\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$ such that [etc.]$\text{''}$ means for different open sets $U$ you may get different functions $g$.  For some reason I wonder if that's what was intended. $\qquad$

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought about that. Well spotted.
My method of choosing just any sets Vn as long as they are increasing in size doesn't account for that.

Perhaps that is part of it.

Comment: On second thought this is not the case. All simply connected domains in $\mathbb{C}$ are homeomorphic to eachother, so if there exists such a function it can be applied to every domain $U$.

Comment: No, $U$ is not assumed to be bounded.